# Mockito Matchers.any(...) on one argument only

Tags: java, testing, mockito, matcher

**I want to do this:**

```
 verify(function, Mockito.times(1)).doSomething(argument1, Matchers.any(Argument2.class));
```

Where **argument1** is a specfic instance of type **Argument1** and **argument2** is any instance of the type **Argument2**.

But I get an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:  Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded. This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Following that advice I can write the following and everything is fine:

```
 verify(function, Mockito.times(1)).doSomething(Matchers.any(Argument1.class), Matchers.any(Argument2.class));
```

Where I am looking for any arguement of type **Argument1** and any argument of type **Argument2**.

How can I acheive this desired behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is more than one possible argument matcher and one is `eq`, which is mentioned in the exception message. Use:

```
verify(function, times(1)).doSomething(eq(arg1), any(Argument2.class));
```

(static imports supposed to be there -- `eq()` is `Matchers.eq()`).

You also have `same()` (which does reference equality, ie `==`), and more generally you can write your own matchers.